# Calling a freeglut function in PyOpenGL prints 'freeglut' and exits

Tags: python, opengl, freeglut, pyopengl

Version: Python 2.7.6 on Ubuntu 14.04

```
>>> import OpenGL
>>> import OpenGL.GLUT
>>> import OpenGL.GLUT.freeglut
>>> OpenGL.GLUT.freeglut.glutSetOption(OpenGL.GLUT.GLUT_ACTION_ON_WINDOW_CLOSE, OpenGL.GLUT.GLUT_ACTION_GLUTMAINLOOP_RETURNS)
```

Running the above in the Python REPL prints `freeglut` to stderr and exits the Python REPL automatically. Why is this happening, and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call `glutInit(sys.argv)` before any other GLUT function. `glutInit` returns the parameter list with the GLUT specific parameters removed, which you can then use instead of `sys.argv` or you replace it with this, i.e. `sys.argv = glutInit(sys.argv)`